# JSON parse error on ajaxcall from homemade php API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

when i try to get the response from the google distancematrixservices i get this error: *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*
if i do a jQuery ajax call from my API:

```
   <?php
     $key = myKey;
     $from = $_GET['from'];
     $to = $_GET['to'];
     $mode = $_GET['mode'];
     $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json…' . urlencode($from) . '&destinations=' . urlencode($to) . '&key='. urlencode($key) .'&travelmode=' . urlencode($mode) . '&departure_time=now';
     $json = file_get_contents($url);
     echo $json;
    ?>
```

javascript ajax call:

```
var getDurationinTraffic=function(){
$.ajax({
  url:'API.php',
  type: 'get',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType:'json',
  data:{
    from: startpoint,
    to: destination,
    mode: 'DRIVING'
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
  },
  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
  },
  statusCode: {
      404: function() {
          alert("oops something went wrong");
      }
  }
});
```

};

both my javascript and API are running on my localhost

Comment: Well the error is in the JSON response, but you didn't post that.

Comment: alrerady fixed the problem myself the problem wasn't in the JSON response,It was a syntaxfault in my api call to google distancematrix correct url: `$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' . urlencode($from) . '&destinations=' . urlencode($to) . '&key='. urlencode($key) .'&travelmode=' . urlencode($mode) . '&departure_time=now';`